# C#: How can I check if the client is using the official application when connecting to the server?

Tags: c#, ssl

I have a tcp client/server. When connecting the client to the server, the client's IP address is written to the logs on the server. 
It is important that only trusted clients can thus make an ip address to the server. How to verify this?

I looked for examples on the internet and i found ssl certificates, but in all examples the certificate check could be disabled by removing one line from the code. It is not safe.

Comment: You cannot trust the application the user is using, you can only trust the user that he is using the right application. If it sounds like a duck, looks like a duck and flies like a duck, how will you know if it is not a duck?

Comment: "check could be disabled" - this check should be done on your server.  How it can be disabled from client?

Comment: @AleksAndreev If someone writes a client app that will talk to the server exactly the same way as the official application the server has no chance to know it is not official. See my duck example

Comment: @SirRufo I mean following: client may use `X509Certificate` to sign it messages. Then on server it is possible to verify authorship of a message

Comment: @AleksAndreev Well that certificate can be used by any client, because anything needed to sign has to be on the client computer and so it can be used without control who is using it